# Can't send form data to php

Tags: php, html

It seems that form data is lost after submit. I am using phpStorm with XAMPP on local machine.

My index.html file:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstName">
    <input type="text" name="lastName">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My test.php file:

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST["firstName"];
$last_name = $_POST["lastName"];
?>
```

And the output:

> Notice: Undefined index: firstName in test.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined index: lastName in test.php on line 3

Comment: you need to close your form tag missing `>` at `</form`

Comment: try to use method GET

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I copy/pasted the code as it is (I didn't even correct the error Saty pointed out) and it *just worked*. Whatever the problem you have is, the code in the question does not demonstrate it.

Comment: @BenM — Putting values in the inputs wouldn't make a difference. An empty string will still give a defined index.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First make sure that those Html and Php files are contained in the same directory. And also make sure you closed the form tag `</form>` since I see it unclosed in the question. 
 You can use the `if (!empty($_POST)){...}` to confirm whether the post has happened or Not !!!.

Comment: "First make sure that those Html and Php files are contained in the same directory" — If they weren't, then the problem would be a 404 error, not a complaint about an Undefined index

Comment: "And also make sure you closed the tag () since I see it unclosed in the question" — As mentioned in the comments, that makes no practical difference to the test case.

Comment: "You can use the if (!empty($_POST)){...} to confirm whether the post has happened" — That doesn't solve the problem. It's basically the same suggestion that every other irrelevant answer on the question has already suggested.

Comment: I solved the problem. For some reason, I was using wrong port on my browser window. And I was so sure that the problem lies in my code that didn't event notice that. Even the problem was not with paths, I accept this answer, because it helped me to find the solution.

Comment: @DainiusGrinciukas I'm happy that it helped you anyway..  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['lastName'])){
    $first_name = $_POST['firstName'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lastName'];
}?>
```

And you need to close your form correctly `</form>`

Comment: That's great as a means of handling errors when data is missing. It doesn't solve the problem of **why** the data is missing though, and that is what the question is asking about.